# Highcharts display date as series label from JSON data?

Tags: highcharts

I have data that can either be weekly or monthly that gets returned as json.

Can somebody explain how I can just return the series in the payload to group by each series? That is, display the x-axis as the label?

I want to use one chart to display (weekly, monthly, daily) with a json data payload but use only one chart to display that json payload for either time slice.

For example:

Weekly Payload:

```
[
     {
        "date-label":"Week 24",
        "series1":789118,
        "series2":49475,
     },
     {
        "date-label":"Week 25",
        "series1":5759546,
        "series2":286657,
     }
 ]
```

Monthly Payload:

```
[
     {
        "date-label":"June",
        "series1":789118,
        "series2":49475,
     },
     {
        "date-label":"July",
        "series1":5759546,
        "series2":286657,
     }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many points do you have?

If there is only a couple (~10?) you can use categories, and then result should be:

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['June', 'July' ... ]
  }, 
  series: [{
    data: [123, 124 ...]
  }, {
    data: [123, 124 ...]
  }]
});
```

If you have more points, so it wouldn't be possible to display all categories, you need to change format from 'Week 24' or 'June' to timestamp, so something like this:

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  }, 
  series: [{
    data: [[timestamp, 123], [timestamp, 124] ...]
  }, {
    data: [[timestamp, 123], [timestamp, 124] ...]
  }]
});
```

Where timestamp is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will most likely go with the latter as there might be more than 10 points but not over 20.. That said, what I'm trying to achieve is use "one" chart that allows for a weekly breakdown as well as a monthly and even a daily for last 10-15 days.  However, I want to use a json payload to pass the data and have the chart render any of those three time slices of data (weekly, monthly, daily).  If I'm passing in time stamp (epoch), how could I acheive that?

Comment: I'm thinking that I will just have to pass back epoch/timestamp for each time slice (daily, monthly, weekly) and display the date accordingly.  I was hoping for a cheap pass a string literal for each datapoint and display the string literal on the x-axis like a date.

Comment: If you will have 20 points, you still can use categories as in first option, but just set `tickInterval: 2` to make enough space for each category - otherwise they will overlap each other.